# Not able to run Jeremy Feinstein sliding menu on android version 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have implemented Sliding menu using Jeremy Feinstein library.
Which is working perfectly fine on Android version : 4.x.x

But when I try to execute on android version : 2.3.x, application crashes with following error.

```
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.variouscal.calculators/com.variouscal.calculators.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setMenu(SlidingMenu.java:375)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at com.variouscal.calculators.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    ... 11 more
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.variouscal.calculators-1.apk]
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
11-29 19:25:52.628: E/AndroidRuntime(26836):    ... 18 more
```

Below is **MainActivity.java** and **SlidingMenuFragment.java**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.variouscal.calculators;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SlidingMenu slidingMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
        slidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        slidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        slidingMenu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_shadow_width);
        slidingMenu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.slidingmenu_shadow);
        slidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        slidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
        slidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.slidingmenu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.slidingMenu.toggle();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (slidingMenu.isMenuShowing()) {
            slidingMenu.toggle();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
            this.slidingMenu.toggle();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

**SlidingMenuFragment.java**

```
package com.variouscal.calculators;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener {

    private ExpandableListView sectionListView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        List<Section> sectionList = createMenu();

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu_fragment, container, false);
        this.sectionListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingmenu_view);
        this.sectionListView.setGroupIndicator(null);

        SectionListAdapter sectionListAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(this.getActivity(), sectionList);
        this.sectionListView.setAdapter(sectionListAdapter);

        this.sectionListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
                return true;
              }
            });

        this.sectionListView.setOnChildClickListener(this);

        int count = sectionListAdapter.getGroupCount();
        for (int position = 0; position < count; position++) {
            this.sectionListView.expandGroup(position);
        }

        return view;
    }

    private List<Section> createMenu() {
        List<Section> sectionList = new ArrayList<Section>();

        Section oDemoSection = new Section("Calculators");
        oDemoSection.addSectionItem(101,"Love Calculator", "slidingmenu_friends");
        oDemoSection.addSectionItem(102, "Age Calculator", "slidingmenu_airport");
        oDemoSection.addSectionItem(103, "BMI Calculator", "slidingmenu_airport");

        Section oGeneralSection = new Section("General");
        oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(201, "Settings", "slidingmenu_settings");
        oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(202, "Rate this app", "slidingmenu_rating");
        oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(203, "Eula", "slidingmenu_eula");
        oGeneralSection.addSectionItem(204, "Quit", "slidingmenu_quit");

        sectionList.add(oDemoSection);
        sectionList.add(oGeneralSection);
        return sectionList;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        switch ((int)id) {
        case 101:
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.variouscal.calculators.LoveCalculator");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 102:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.variouscal.calculators.AgeCalculator");
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case 103:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent("com.variouscal.calculators.BmiCalculator");
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case 202:
            //TODO
            break;
        case 203:
            //TODO
            break;
        case 204:
            //TODO
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I make it work for Android version : 2.3.x.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code. This is how I did it and it worked for me. Hope this code helps you.

```
package com.example.calculators;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.slidingmenu);
        getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is my slidingmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragback"
        android:name="com.example.calculators.ListFrag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Sorry for being so late. Please make sure you have used android.support.v4.app.Fragment .

Comment: I have edited my code and I have tried this on android version: 2.3.6 and it is working perfectly.

Comment: Hi pooja I am also facing the same error. My sliding menu is working perfectly on 4.0.x but not working on 2.3.5 please help me.not working. Can you please tell me what you did to make it working?